# Calling multiple functions using some generic function call in C

Tags: c, function, pointers, generics

I want to be able to call multiple functions using a single generic function call.

Currently I am trying to implement something like this:

```
main()
{
    generic();
}

A(){.....};

B(){.....};

C(){.....};
```

Where I call from `main()` some generic function, which, in turn, is supposed to be able to call the functions: A(), B(), C().

How can I implement this in C?

Comment: you can simply declare the functions in constructor

Comment: Please clarify your question. Do you want `generic` to always call all of the funtions - or do you want it to call one of the functions based on a parameter?

Comment: @HeenaGoyal Do we have constructor in C ?

Comment: @HeenaGoyal: There is no constructor in c. But do you have any other way to do it

Comment: Yes i want generic to call all functions without specifying there names , something like  packet broadcast in computer networks

Comment: could you explain more about your requirement so that i can help you more precisely? because how can you call all the function defined in application you have to specify some specification which you want to call.

Comment: i want to check one global variable in main function by all functions in project. But in C always program start from main() i always had to call that function in order to make that function work. how I can make these function automatically check value of global

Comment: extern int a=1;
main()
{                                                                           a=1;                                                                     
 generic();// this is generic call which invokes all fun.
}

int A(parameters)
{
 if (a==1){
  //do something
}
char B(parameters)
{
 if (a==1){
  //do something
}

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by using function pointers. Please refer on "how to use function pointers in C"

Comment: i refered that but i could't find the answer.Give me any reference link if you have thanks

Comment: please see answer posted by user207064 below. Hope it helps you

Answer (score 1):

You have to use function pointers as below.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void A(void);
void B(void);
void C(void);
typedef void (*foo_ptr_t)( void );
foo_ptr_t foo_ptr_array[3]; //fucntion pointers of type foo_ptr_t
main()
{
    int i = 0;
    foo_ptr_array[0] = A; //assign function to each function pointer
    foo_ptr_array[1] = B;
    foo_ptr_array[2] = C;
    for(i = 0; i<3; i++)
        foo_ptr_array[i](); //call functions using function pointer
}

void A()
{
    printf("We are in A\n");
}

void B()
{
    printf("We are in B\n");
}

void C()
{
    printf("We are in C\n");
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer but i wanted this more dynamic suppose if we dont know function names in project, how to achieve that?.

Comment: if you don't know function names, then how do you want to call them? What DO you know about them then?

Comment: ok then suppose if we have function names and other details. i want to check one global variable in main function by all functions in project. But in C always program start from main() i always had to call that function in order to make that function work. how I can make these function automatically check value of global

Comment: extern int a=1; main() { a=1; generic();// this is generic call which invokes all fun. } int A(parameters) { if (a==1){ //do something } char B(parameters) { if (a==1){ //do something }

Answer (score 0):

You can use function pointers, if all functions you want to call have same prototype.